# Name of number representation

Tags: notation, number-systems

What do you call a number representation which constists only of integers, arithmetic operators and exponents/roots? I.e. no decimal numbers, trigonometric expressions, etc.

EDIT: To clarify, I want to represent e.g. the length of the hypotenuse of a 45-45-90 triangle with sides 1 as $\sqrt{2}$, not 1.414..., nor ${1}\over{\sin{\pi/4}}$. Similarly, I want to represent $\sin{\pi/12}$ as $\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}$, not 0.258...

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: How do arithmetic operations belong to a number representation?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could call it a "radical representation", as the word "radical" encompasses square roots, cube roots, etc., but whatever you decide to call it, I hope you will not expect your reader to understand it without showing an example or two.